# Export nested Gridview to Excel error

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I need to export nested Gridview to Excel with the following code that I get from search, but when I click the Export button it raised an error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

This is the code:

```
protected void ExportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("GridView_Data");
            GridView grvPayrollDetails = (GridView)grvPayroll.Rows[1].FindControl("grvPayrollDetails");
            foreach (TableCell cell in grvPayroll.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
            }
            foreach (TableCell cell in grvPayrollDetails.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
            }
            dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grvPayroll.Rows)
            {
                GridView grvPayrollDetailscell = (row.FindControl("grvPayrollDetails") as GridView);
                for (int j = 0; j < grvPayrollDetailscell.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells[1].Text, row.Cells[2].Text, grvPayrollDetailscell.Rows[j].Cells[0].Text, grvPayrollDetailscell.Rows[j].Cells[1].Text);
                }
            }
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=grvPayrollDetails.xlsx");
                using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
```

grvPayroll is the Master Gridview and Gridview grvPayrollDetails is the nested child Gridview. Please help!
I followed this guide: [Export Nested GridView (GridView inside GridView) to Excel in ASP.Net](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/147544/Export-Nested-GridView-GridView-inside-GridView-to-Excel-in-ASPNet/)

And this is the Nested Gridview :
[Nested Gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sVFU.png)

Comment: Use the debugger Luke! and check your values which are out of range. On which line you get this exception by the way?

Comment: It raised an error at this line:  GridView grvPayrollDetails = (GridView)grvPayroll.Rows[1].FindControl("grvPayrollDetails"); but i cannot understand why?

Comment: So your gridview _really_ has 2 rows before on that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
            /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
               server control at run time. */
        }
        protected void ExportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grvPayroll.AllowPaging = false;
            var grvPayrollDetails = new GridView();
            for (var i = 0; i < grvPayroll.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                grvPayrollDetails = (GridView)grvPayroll.Rows[i].FindControl("grvPayrollDetails");
                grvPayrollDetails.AllowPaging = false;
                BindGrid(SortField);
            }
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PayrollExport.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                grvPayrollDetails.AllowPaging = false;
                this.BindGrid(SortField);
                grvPayrollDetails.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
                grvPayrollDetails.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                grvPayrollDetails.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
                grvPayrollDetails.RenderControl(hw);
                Response.Write(Regex.Replace(sw.ToString(), "(<a[^>]*>)|(</a>)", " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your following line `GridView grvPayrollDetails = (GridView)grvPayroll.Rows[1].FindControl("grvPayrollDetails");` with below code

```
GridView grvPayrollDetails = null;

foreach (GridViewRow row in grvPayroll.Rows)
{
    if (row.HasControls())
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in row.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.ID == "grvPayrollDetails" && grvPayrollDetails != null)
            {
                grvPayrollDetails = (GridView)ctrl;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (grvPayrollDetails != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

you should modify your for loop to run for count - 1, and use if condition to check `row.Cells` should be `>= 3`

```
for (int j = 0; j < grvPayrollDetailscell.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
{
    if(row.Cells.Count >= 3)
    {
                    dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells[1].Text, row.Cells[2].Text, grvPayrollDetailscell.Rows[j].Cells[0].Text, grvPayrollDetailscell.Rows[j].Cells[1].Text);
```

Also makesure your dt.Columns have value before removing column at 0 index

```
if(dt.Columns.Count > 0)
{
    dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: I modified the code , but it still get the same error at line: GridView grvPayrollDetails = (GridView)grvPayroll.Rows[1].FindControl("grvPayrollDetails");

Comment: have you add row.Cells.Count >= 3 condition

Comment: Yes,I did. but it still get the same error at line: GridView grvPayrollDetails = (GridView)grvPayroll.Rows[1].FindControl("grvPayrollDetails");

Comment: hi, i modified the code to correct error line in the your code

Comment: I tried all your code but all failed. Thank you for your help , I try another method , no error occurr but I ony get an excel file with header no data . Pls, visit this thread, maybe you can help me :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940893/export-nested-gridview-blank-cell-error