# Export nested Gridview blank cell error

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I followed this guide : [Export Multi-Level Nested GridView to Excel using OpenXml in ASP.Net](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/145808/Export-Multi-Level-Nested-GridView-to-Excel-using-OpenXml-in-ASPNet/)

And modified the code for my case as follows:

```
 protected void ExportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable("GridView_Data");
        grvPayroll.AllowPaging = false;
        var grvPayrollDetails = new GridView();
        for (var i = 0; i < grvPayroll.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            grvPayrollDetails = (GridView) grvPayroll.Rows[i].FindControl("grvPayrollDetails");
            grvPayrollDetails.AllowPaging = false;
        }
        foreach (TableCell cell in grvPayrollDetails.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.Text != "&nbsp;")
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
            }
        }

        foreach (GridViewRow row in grvPayroll.Rows)
        {
            var grvPayrollDetailscell = (row.FindControl("grvPayrollDetails") as GridView);
            for (var j = 0; j < grvPayrollDetailscell.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells[1].Text, row.Cells[2].Text, grvPayrollDetailscell.Rows[j].Cells[1].Text,
                    grvPayrollDetailscell.Rows[j].Cells[2].Text);
            }
        }

        using (var wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridView.xlsx");

            using (var MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

No error occurred, but the export file just contain the header , all cells are empty. The export excel file with exactly the header name and the number of rows. Why? Please help!
Here is the picture:
[Exported File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mz1W.png)

Comment: In the example, they used BoundField but in my project I use TemplateField. Is it the cause of blank cell error? Line :  dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells[1].Text, row.Cells[2].Text, grvPayrollDetailscell.Rows[j].Cells[1].Text,
                    grvPayrollDetailscell.Rows[j].Cells[2].Text);  , when bugging, DataTable is null . Why? Please help!

Comment: OpenXML seem does not work with Template Field, so I try to use HTMLTextWriter and everything work well.